# Mandatory Alpha and Power Values to sum up to 1.0?

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power

I am confused about an Ethic Commision Comment about the definitions of alpha and power (1-beta) to calculate the sample size for an actually quite simple 2 independent samples t-test based experiment.

Despite the pre-calculation of Cohen's d I was always told to typically use the following settings:
alpha = 0.05 and 1-beta = 0.8

The comment mentioned above stated that alpha and 1-beta always must sum upo to "1.0".
In other words: if alpha = 0.05 1-beta must be 0.95.

This would be completely new to me and up ot now I did not find any rationale to support this comment.

Maybe I missed something important about a new "recommendation" - in any case:
all of your comments are highly appreciated to get things sorted out!

With kind regards
Thomas

Comment: This has no basis in any statistical theory, because alpha and beta need to be established according to your investigative needs.  Notice, please, that "$1-\beta=0.8$" is not a well-defined criterion: you also need to state the effect size at which this value should apply.  That's another reason why it's meaningless to require that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ sum to unity (or anything else).

Comment: @whuber: of course Cohen's d was taken into account based on preliminary experiments. My question was focused on  and 1- and if both of them must sum up to 1.0, respectively.

Comment: The question isn't mathematically meaningful because you are free to change your target of Cohen's d: in other words, you are using three numbers to represent just a pair of risks.  Another way to put it is this: if your reviewer insists you use $\alpha+\beta=1,$ you can always accomplish that by changing Cohen's d.  This could be viewed as a form of standardization: perhaps the reviewer just wants you to report the effect size that corresponds to 95% confidence and 95% power.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for that in general. The rationale might be the cost of both types of errors is the same. Nonetheless, it is very common to use, for example, one-sided $\alpha=0.025$ and $1-\beta$ equal 0.8 or 0.9.

Something interesting happens though if you do use $\alpha=\beta$ when you are testing $H_0:\theta \le 0$ with a postulated value of $\theta_1$. In that case, the two-sided $(1-2\alpha)100$% confidence interval will have width of $\theta_1$. So, if the estimated value of the parameter is between $0$ and $\theta_1$,  the CI will include either $0$ or $\theta_1$ and exclude the other (ignore the case when the estimate is exactly equal to $\theta_1/2$). That avoids the undesirable outcome where the CI includes both.

Comment: thank you for your comment. The proposal about setting = with a "postulated" value of  is completely new to me, however testing like that might have some advantages I have to think about.